# List all directories recursively in a tree format

Tags: shell

I want to simulate a `tree` command using Shell Script that displays all the directories recursively in this format:

```
.
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
    |-- Lorem
    |-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
`-- Lorem
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try doing this (not exactly the same output, but very close) :

```
find ./ -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

From http://mlsamuelson.com/content/tree-approximation-using-find-and-sed

### with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
find . -type d -print 2>/dev/null|awk '!/\.$/ {for (i=1;i<NF;i++){d=length($i);if ( d < 5  && i != 1 )d=5;printf("%"d"s","|")}print "---"$NF}'  FS='/'
```

See http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/50806-directory-tree.html

Comment: Awesome! But how can I do that using `awk` instead of `sed`?

Answer (score 15):

You can just launch :

```
tree .
```

OR

```
tree $absolute/path/of/your/dir
```

If you want to display the hidden files.
By default tree does not print hidden files (those beginning with a dot '.'), just type:

```
tree -a .
```

This is what tree command do.

Comment: Have you read the question? "I want to simulate a `tree` command using..."

Comment: One explanation is that some linux machines are blocked from downloading `tree`, and need a DIY solutions.

Comment: The `tree` command doesn't "simulate" the `tree` command. It IS the `tree` command, so no soup for you.

Answer (score 4):

Modifying sputnick's answer to get closer to your original format (which I prefer):

```sh
find ./ -type d -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/; /;g;s;/ ;    ;g;s;^ /$;.;;s; /;|-- ;g'
```

The only difference now is the last line doesn't start with a backtick:

```
.
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
    |-- Lorem
    |-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
|-- Lorem
```

### with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```sh
find . -type d -print 2>/dev/null | awk '!/\.$/ {for (i=1;i<NF-1;i++){printf("    ")}printf("|-- ")};{print $NF}' FS='/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Modified base on the awk one from http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/50806-directory-tree.html

```
pwd;find . -type d -print 2>/dev/null|awk '!/\.$/ {for (i=1;i<NF-1;i++){printf("│   ")}print "├── "$NF}'  FS='/'
```

Output looks more similar to `tree`:

```
/etc
├── sudoers.d
├── susehelp.d
│   ├── htdig
├── sysconfig
│   ├── SuSEfirewall2.d
│   │   ├── services
│   ├── network
│   │   ├── if-down.d
│   │   ├── if-up.d
│   │   ├── providers
│   │   ├── scripts
│   ├── scripts
├── sysctl.d
├── systemd
│   ├── system
│   │   ├── default.target.wants
│   │   ├── getty.target.wants
│   │   ├── multi-user.target.wants
```

Answer (score 0):

ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^/]*//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'

taken from here: http://www.centerkey.com/tree/